# connect is not a function when connecting to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Error occurs when trying to run the function from the `mongodb` website that connects code to db.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb')

const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

Error is:

```
client.connect(err => {
  ^

    TypeError: client.connect is not a function
```

I have `mongodb` installed via `npm` and uri defined as the string they gave. Do I need anything else?

Comment: Where did you get example code from? Can you add source?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb examples dont create a new object from `MongoClient` but instead they are using directly `MongoClient.connect()`

Comment: Do a dump / inpsect of `client` - is there any error info in there? Is it null?

Comment: check @jozev answer below. it will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try connecting this way:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const uri = "yourUri...";
const databaseName = "yourDBName";

MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log("Connection failed for some reason");
  }
  console.log("Connection established - All well");
  const db = client.db(databaseName);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that you should import the MongoClient class:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

Instead of the following line in your code: <strike>`const MongoClient = require("mongodb");`</strike>

Comment: You can also use destructuring `const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");`

Answer (score 3):

For that problem, the standard solution is to import `clientPromise` because versions higher than 3.9/4.0 do not have `import {Mongoclient}` command.

Then also, if you want to use `MongoClient` then,

1. Stop the current running server
2. Type `npm i mongodb@3.5.9` in terminal
3. Restart your server by `npm/yarn run dev`

Now it will work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using older version of MongoClient then try to install mongo client 2.2.33.

```
npm uninstall mongodb
npm install mongodb@2.2.33
```

If you are using the newer version (3.0 and above) of mongo client then modify the code as shown below.

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function(err, client){
  if(err) throw err;
  let db = client.db('test');
  db.collection('devices').find().toArray(function(err, result){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    client.close();
    });
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient();
```

Comment: Take a look again at [answer]. Without any explanation, it's unclear how this differs from answers already posted