# Why am I getting this typeerror for mongodb.connect?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to write a todo app and connect to the database I want to pull from and write to, but I keep getting this error.

```
mongodb.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true, 
useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, client) {
  db = client.db()
  app.listen(3000)
})
```

THE ERROR: "TypeError: mongodb.getConnection is not a function
at Object. (/Users/auston.ivison/Desktop/todo-app/server.js:8:9)

Comment: Are you using mongodb or mongoose package?

Comment: mongodb, do I need to install the mongoose package to get the connect method to work?

Comment: Install mongoose for better usage. See my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [connect is not a function when connecting to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026108/connect-is-not-a-function-when-connecting-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

First import mongoose package

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Then connect to database

```
mongoose.connect(connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
    .catch(console.log);
```