# MongoDB Atlas with NodeJS using Mongodb is not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to connect with MongoDB, error pointed toward connect while it's keyword itself. I didn't know what the issue here.
Error is :

```
mongodb.connect(
         ^

TypeError: mongodb.connect is not a function
   
let express= require('express')
let mongodb= require('mongodb').mongodb


let app = express()
let db

    let connectionString = 'mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.sfis6s3.mongodb.net/ToDoApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
     mongodb.connect(
         connectionString,{useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, client){
      
            db = client.db()
           
     })
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is for that you must import MongoClient class

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

reference:
[connect is not a function when connecting to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026108/connect-is-not-a-function-when-connecting-to-mongodb)